# Sass Null Exception with no error message

Tags: java, css, gradle, sass

I am trying to use scss with gradle to generate css files. However I get an error when running the gradle build

The error I am receiving is

```
Execution failed for task ':sassCompile'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

I have the following scss code

brand_oit_appdev.scss

```
//brand_oit_appdev

@import 'bootstrap_overrides';


header {
  .navbar-header {
    margin-left: 7px;

    a.umn-homepage {
      background-image: url(../../images/revised-wordmark-transparent.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      margin-top: 4px;
      margin-left: -10px;
      height: 70px;
      width: 305px;
      display: block;

      span {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
    }
  }

  .global-links {
    margin-top:5px;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: .9em;

    ul {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    a {
      color: $umn-white;
    }
  }

  .search-form {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: -15px;

    input {
      width: 15em !important;
      border-radius: 0 !important;
      border: none;
      transition: width .3s !important;

      &:focus {
        width: 21em !important;
      }
    }

    button {
      border: none;
      background-color: inherit;
      color: $umn-white;
      font-weight: bold;

      span {
        font-size: 1.8em;
      }

      &:hover, &:focus {
        color: $umn-white;
      }
    }
  }

  .navbar-brand {
    img {
      width: 32px;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      margin-right: 14px;
    }
  }

  .application-title {
    font-weight: 900;
  }
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
  /* Retina-specific stuff here */
  .navbar-header {
    a.umn-homepage {
      background-image: url(../../images/revised-wordmark-transparent@2x.png) !important;
      background-size: 410px 159px !important;
    }
  }
}

h1.page-header {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.table-nonfluid {
  width: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  .application-title {
    font-size: $font-size-h3 !important;
  }
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 6em;
}
table {
  .numeric {
    text-align: right;
  }
}
footer {
  font-size: .9em;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4.5em;
  text-align: center;
}

blockquote footer{
  position:relative;
  height:inherit;
  text-align:inherit;

}

.label-style{
  /* mimics Bootstrap's label styling */
  max-width:100%;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  font-weight:bold;
}


*:focus{

  border-color: rgba(82,168,236,.8)      !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6) !important;
  outline: 0 none !important;
   outline: thin dotted \9; /* IE6-9 */


}
```

leaguespartan.scss

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'League Spartan';
    src: url('leaguespartan-bold.eot');
    src: url('leaguespartan-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold.svg#league_spartanbold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

bootstrap_overrides.scss

```
// bootstrap_overrides
@import 'leaguespartan';
@import '../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';

$umn-maroon: #7a0019;
$umn-maroon-dark: #570412; // from portal nav
$umn-gold: #ffcc33;
$umn-white: #ffffff;

$font-family-sans-serif: "Avenir", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$title-font: $font-family-sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 16px;

$icon-font-path: "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
$include-global-links: true;

$navbar-padding-horizontal: 0px;
//$navbar-height: 62px;
$navbar-margin-bottom: 0;
$navbar-border-radius: none;

$navbar-default-bg: $umn-gold;
$navbar-default-border: none;
$navbar-default-link-color: $umn-maroon;
$navbar-default-link-hover-color: $umn-maroon;
$navbar-default-link-active-color: $umn-maroon;

$navbar-inverse-bg: $umn-maroon;
$navbar-inverse-border: none;
$navbar-inverse-link-color: $umn-maroon;
$navbar-inverse-link-hover-color: $umn-maroon;
$navbar-inverse-link-active-color: $umn-maroon;
$navbar-inverse-link-active-bg: darken($umn-maroon, 5%);
$navbar-inverse-toggle-hover-bg: darken($umn-maroon, 5%);
$navbar-inverse-toggle-icon-bar-bg: $umn-maroon;
$navbar-inverse-toggle-border-color: none;

$breadcrumb-bg: $umn-white;
$breadcrumb-padding-horizontal: 0;
$breadcrumb-padding-vertical: 1.5em;


caption,
.text-muted,
blockquote footer, blockquote small, blockquote .small,
h1 small, h1 .small, h2 small, h2 .small, h3 small, h3 .small, h4 small, h4 .small, h5 small, h5 .small, h6 small, h6 .small, .h1 small, .h1 .small, .h2 small, .h2 .small, .h3 small, .h3 .small, .h4 small, .h4 .small, .h5 small, .h5 .small, .h6 small, .h6 .small{
    color:#666 /*Should the Bootstrap's lighter gray be reset? */
}



.btn-success, .btn-info, .btn-warning, .btn-danger, .label-success, .label-info, .label-warning, .label-danger{
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #000000;
}
```

Here is my build.gradle, well the relevant parts at least

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java'
    id "it.tellnet.sass" version "1.2"
}

apply plugin: "it.tellnet.sass"
configurations {
    runtime
    configurations.runtime.extendsFrom configurations.sassRuntime
}

sass {
    sassDir = 'server/src/main/webapp/stylesheets/scss'
    cssDir = 'server/src/main/webapp/stylesheets/css'
    minify = false
    silenceErrors = false
}
```

The error does go away is I move the imports from bootstrap_overrides to the same line, but the output file is basically the oit-brand file without any substitutions and around 150 lines. I have compiled these files using ruby and the css is around 5000 lines long.

Here is the stacktrace as requested

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sassCompile'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:194)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:36)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:118)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.util.ColorUtil.adjust(ColorUtil.java:572)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.util.ColorUtil.darken(ColorUtil.java:584)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.parser.function.DarkenFunctionGenerator.computeForArgumentList(DarkenFunctionGenerator.java:42)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.parser.function.AbstractFunctionGenerator.compute(AbstractFunctionGenerator.java:72)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.parser.LexicalUnitImpl.evaluateFunctionsAndExpressions(LexicalUnitImpl.java:826)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.VariableNode.traverse(VariableNode.java:84)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.Node.traverseChildren(Node.java:227)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.controldirective.TemporaryNode.traverseChildren(TemporaryNode.java:53)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.visitor.ImportNodeHandler.traverse(ImportNodeHandler.java:97)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.ImportNode.traverse(ImportNode.java:99)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.Node.traverseChildren(Node.java:227)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.controldirective.TemporaryNode.traverseChildren(TemporaryNode.java:53)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.visitor.ImportNodeHandler.traverse(ImportNodeHandler.java:97)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.ImportNode.traverse(ImportNode.java:99)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.Node.traverseChildren(Node.java:227)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.controldirective.TemporaryNode.traverseChildren(TemporaryNode.java:53)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.visitor.ImportNodeHandler.traverse(ImportNodeHandler.java:97)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.ImportNode.traverse(ImportNode.java:99)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.Node.traverseChildren(Node.java:227)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.tree.Node.traverseChildren(Node.java:214)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet.traverse(ScssStylesheet.java:298)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet.compile(ScssStylesheet.java:267)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet.compile(ScssStylesheet.java:242)
        at com.vaadin.sass.internal.ScssStylesheet$compile$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at it.tellnet.gradle.SassCompilerImpl.exec(SassCompilerImpl.groovy:31)
        at it.tellnet.gradle.SassCompilerImpl$exec.call(Unknown Source)
        at it.tellnet.gradle.SassCompileTask$_compileAllCss_closure1.doCall(SassCompileTask.groovy:30)
        at it.tellnet.gradle.SassCompileTask.compileAllCss(SassCompileTask.groovy:19)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:624)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:607)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
        ... 69 more


BUILD FAILED
```

I am at a loss of what to do to fix this issue.

Comment: maybe it's a bug in a gradle plugin. Just in case, re-run the build using --stacktrace. You'll get your NullPointerException stracktrace. It may help you do find why you got it.

Comment: @dwursteisen I have narrowed it down to the bootstrap import. When I comment that line out, the scss compiles. I have also added the stacktrace to the original question

Comment: I get the same exception in the same place (`adjust` call), seems weird

Comment: For a future reference: in my case problem was with a color variable defined as `rgba(255, 41, 41)` which is incorrect and after replacing it with `rgb(255, 41, 41)` I got everything to compile just fine.